# Warning: Missing argument 2 for shortcode_atts()

Tags: wordpress, arguments, shortcode

I've built a website locally, and everything seems to be working fine. When I migrated it all to a test server, I got an error on some of my short-codes.

The two short-codes in question are as follows:

```
function gallery_image( $atts, $content = null ) {
extract( shortcode_atts(
$atts ) );
return '<div class="twocol"><a rel="prettyPhoto[gal]" href="'. $link .'"><img src="' .     do_shortcode($content) . '"/></a></div>';
}
add_shortcode('image', 'gallery_image');
```

I'm using "[show_info date="Nov. 4, 2013" by="William Shakespeare"]" to execute this.

AND

```
function show_opening( $atts, $content = null ) {
extract( shortcode_atts(
$atts ) );
return '<div class="show-opening"><span>On Stage:</span> '. $date .'<span>by:</span> ' .     $by . '</div>'; 
}
add_shortcode('show_info', 'show_opening');
```

I'm using "[image link="/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/RomeoAndJuliet-Gallery01.jpg"]/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/RomeoAndJuliet-Gallery01.jpg[/image]" to execute this.

I've never seen this before, and can't understand why it worked fine locally, but only displayed this error once loaded to a web-server. Any idea why this might be happening? Or any suggestions on how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass supported attributes and their defaults in first argument...

[Read more](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts)

Comment: Thanks! I knew there was something missing in the function. That worked perfectly.